Points of discontinuity of greatest Integer function
So here's my problem
Find the points of discontinuity of $[x^2]$ in the interval$[-1,2]$ where [] is  the G.I.F.
I am not able to understand why at $2^{1/2}$ and $3^{1/2}$ the function is being discontinuous .
The value of $2^{1/2}$ is $1.41$ if where take $1.41+h$ or $1.41-h$ where h is infinitesimally small number the function still give us $1$ so $L.H.L$=$R.H.L$ but the answer says at $2^{1/2}$ it is discontinuous. Please clarify Thanks :)

Your last paragraph is wrong. Points $\sqrt{2} - h$ slightly to the left of $\sqrt{2}$ have squares which are slightly less than $2$, so $[(\sqrt{2} - h)^2] = 1$. Likewise near $\sqrt{3}$, you have $[(\sqrt{3} - h)^2] = 2$

I think your issue may be in rounding $2^{1/2}$ to two decimal places.

@MPW Got it yes I was wrong  , I did drew a wrong rough sketch

@DMcMor Yes sir the issue is resolved thanks a lot :)

Note that in general, functions like $f(x) = \lfloor g(x) \rfloor$, where $g$ is continuous, could potentially have a discontinuity where $g(x)$ is an integer (but not necessarily, as your example at $x=0$ shows).

@MPW Thanks alot sir :))
